# Calculating the Standard Error and Confidence Interval for Cohen's Quadratic Kappa

Tags: confidence-interval, python, standard-error, cohens-kappa

I need to evaluate the performance of a machine learning application. One of the evaluation metrics chosen is Cohen's Quadratic Kappa. I found [this Python tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/aroraaman/quadratic-kappa-metric-explained-in-5-simple-steps) on how to calculate Cohen's Quadratic Kappa. What is missing, however, is how to calculate the confidence interval.

Let's walk through my example (I use a smaller data set for the sake of simplicity). I use NumPy and Scipy Stats for this purpose:

```
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
```

This is my confusion matrix:

```
# x: actuals, y: predictions
confusion_matrix = np.array([
    [9, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
], dtype=np.int)
rows = confusion_matrix.shape[0]
cols = confusion_matrix.shape[1]
```

I calculate a weight matrix and histograms:

```
weights = np.zeros((rows, cols))
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        weights[r, c] = float(((r-c)**2)/(rows*cols))
hist_actual = np.sum(confusion_matrix, axis=0)
hist_prediction = np.sum(confusion_matrix, axis=1)
```

The expected prediction quality by mere chance is calculated as follows:

```
expected = np.outer(hist_actual, hist_prediction)
```

This matrix, and the actual confusion matrix, are normalized:

```
expected_norm = expected / expected.sum()
confusion_matrix_norm = confusion_matrix / confusion_matrix.sum()
```

Now I calculate the numerator (actual observed agreement) and the denominator (expected agreement by chance):

```
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        numerator += weights[r, c] * confusion_matrix_norm[r, c]
        denominator += weights[r, c] * expected_norm[r, c]
```

Cohen's Kappa can now be calculated as:

```
weighted_kappa = (1 - (numerator/denominator))
```

Which gives me a result of **0.817**.

Now to my question: I need to calculate the standard error, in order to calculate the confidence interval. Here's my approach:

```
#            p(1-p)
# sek = sqrt -------
#            n(1-e)²
#
# p: numerator (actual observed agreement)
# e: denominator (expected agreement by chance)
# n: total number of predictions
total = hist_actual.sum()
sek = sqrt((numerator * (1 - numerator)) / (total * (1 - denominator) ** 2))
```

Can I use the total number of predictions, even though I calculate with a normalized numerator and denominator? This would result in a standard error of kappa of **0.023**.

The 95% confidence interval then is just straightforward:

```
alpha = 0.95
margin = (1 - alpha) / 2  # two-tailed test
x = norm.ppf(1 - margin)
lower = weighted_kappa - x * sek
upper = weighted_kappa + x * sek
```

Which gives an interval of **[0.772;0.861]**.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know anything about Cohen's Quadratic Kappa beyond what you have written, I would fall back to [the bootstrap method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Approach).

To bootstrap sample the CQK score, resample with replacement from your set of predicted ratings. Run these resampled predictions through the CQK score calculation, and you will get a new CQK score. Compute new CQK scores in this way a number of times, at least 100. The standard deviation of this bootstrapped CQK sample is the standard error of the mean CQK score.

Using this approach, I get a standard error around **0.057**, from which you know how to find the confidence interval. Another approach is to directly calculate 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles (`np.percentile`) of the bootstrapped CQK scores as your confidence interval.

```
def extract_data_from_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix):
    y_true = []
    y_pred = []
    for i, row in enumerate(confusion_matrix):
        for j, qty in enumerate(row):
            y_true.extend([i]*qty)
            y_pred.extend([j]*qty)

    return y_true, y_pred


def bootstrap_cqk(y_true, y_pred):
    num_resamples = 100

    Y = np.array([y_true, y_pred]).T

    weighted_kappas = []
    for i in range(num_resamples):
        Y_resample = np.array(random.choices(Y, k=len(Y)))
        y_true_resample = Y_resample[:, 0]
        y_pred_resample = Y_resample[:, 1]
        weighted_kappa = cqk_score(y_true_resample, y_pred_resample)
        weighted_kappas.append(weighted_kappa)

    return weighted_kappas


def calculate_standard_error():

    confusion_matrix = np.array([
        [9, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ], dtype=np.int)

    y_true, y_pred = extract_data_from_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix)
    weighted_kappas = bootstrap_cqk(y_true, y_pred)
    return np.std(weighted_kappas)
```